# Batch Script: gpg2 decrypt hangs when it is used with 'for files' on command line

Tags: batch-file, encryption, gnupg, pgp, forfiles

I want to decrypt all .pgp files present in a folder. Assuming the folder has .pgp files only, I am using the following command to automate the task:

```
forfiles /p "D:\sourcing" /c "cmd /c D:\PGP\GnuPG\gpg2 --batch --passphrase abcxyz--output @path\@fname --decrypt @path\@file"
```

But this command hangs on the terminal.

I am able to decrypt one file at a time using the same gpg2 command
eg: Below command just works fine.

```
D:\PGP\GnuPG\gpg2 --batch --passphrase abcxyz --output D:\sourcing\abc.txt --decrypt D:\sourcing\abc.pgp
```

Comment: I recommend to remove **@path**-variable, because "D:\sourcing" becomes working-directory for command line: `gpg2 --batch --passphrase abcxyz--output @fname --decrypt @file`. Or you can use backslash to divide path and filename `@path\@fname`. Use `echo`-command to debug your code: `forfiles /p "D:\sourcing" /c "cmd /c echo D:\PGP\GnuPG\gpg2 -. .."`

Comment: Thanks, I do have a backslash between @path\@fname but somehow it is removed from text on posting the question, I'll debug further with echo

Comment: I was able to decrypt files after using just fname and file but still after the completion of the command I get following messages at the end

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error

Although files are decrypted successfully. This might fail any job which is calling this batch script

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `forfiles`. A standard `For` command is simpler and faster.

Comment: `FOR %%G IN ("D:\sourcing\*.pgp") DO "D:\PGP\GnuPG\gpg2" --batch --passphrase abcxyz --output "%%~dpnG" --decrypt "%%~G"`

Comment: `@path` expands to the full path including the file name, so `@path\@file` makes no sense; `@fname` is the pure base name, so the extension `.txt` is missing…